# How to fix .AddServices() error - extension) IServiceCollection IServiceCollection.AddServices(IConfiguration configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am getting an error with .AddServices() in public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) when I run my code

I have tried adding packages and updating,

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddServices(IServiceCollection, IConfiguration)'

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddServices()
            .AddBtcLogger()
            .AddHsts(options => { options.Preload = true; })
            .AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.RedirectStatusCode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            })
            .AddBtcSwagger(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .AddResponseCompression()
            .AddMvc()

            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Comment: `AddServices` expects you to pass in `IConfiguration`, which you're not doing.

Comment: What package is this extension method from?